# What can $I\Delta_0$ prove?

Tags: lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic

What combinatorial and number-theoretic propositions can $I\Delta_0$ prove? Obviously there are an infinitude of them, but what are some well known theorems that can be proved in $I\Delta_0$, if any?

Comment: A good place to start learning about what can be done in $I\Delta_0$ is the book Metamathematics of First-Order Arithmetic by Petr Hájek and Pavel Pudlák, a free copy of which can be accessed via the link below (especially in Chapter V). Note the $I\Delta_0$ is referred to as $I\Sigma_0$ in the book. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421926#toc

Comment: I skimmed that chapter before I posted my question. All I could find was information about what kind of coding is possible for arithmetizing syntax in $I\Delta_0$, but no standard theorems about combinatorics or number theory. Did I miss something?

Comment: The following thesis investigated the reverse mathematics of bounded arithmetic: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/Students/ojakian.pdf

Comment: https://users.math.cas.cz/~jerabek/papers/phd.pdf

Comment: They considered several theorems in mathematics including some in the combinatorics and formalized them in essentially fragments of $I\Delta_0$ or its fragments with an additional axiom which says $x^{\log x}$ is a total function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since no one else is biting, I'll answer, and thanks to comments I now this is accurate:

$I\Delta_0$ can prove several basic theorems:

- Every square equals 0 or 1 mod 4
- No prime has a rational square root
- The only solutions to $x^3+y^3=z^3$ or $x^4+y^4=z^4$ are trivial
- Every $x$ is divisible by a prime $p$ with $p \le x$

(The standard proofs can be reproduced in $I\Delta_0$, since they do not require any lists or sequences or products thereof. The last claim is proved in $I\Delta_0$ in a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275173) by D'Aquino.)

$I\Delta_0$ seems not to be able to prove that:

- there are arbitrarily large primes
- every prime of the form $4m+1$ can be written as $a^2+b^2$

(The first is a [well-known](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/gasarch/TOPICS/provephp.pdf) open problem due to Wilkie)

$I\Delta_0$ cannot prove that:

- the functions $x^{\log x}$, $x!$, or $x^y$ are total
- there are solutions to the Pell equation $x^2-Ny^2=1$

(The $x^{\log x}$ is [due](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/parikh/paper.pdf) to Parikh; the Pell equation result is [due](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007295000186?via%3Dihub) to D'Aquino.)

But $I\Delta_0(exp)$, i.e. the theory $I\Delta_0$ in the language with exponentiation, seems  to prove

- every theorem published in the Annals of Mathematics whose statement involves only finitary mathematical objects

(This is a well-known [conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic#Friedman%27s_grand_conjecture) due to Friedman.)

Comment: $x^{\log x}$ is not provably total in $I\Delta_0$, by Parikh theorem. See: https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/parikh/paper.pdf

Comment: As far as I am aware, $I\Delta_0$ is *not* known to prove Fermat’s two-square theorem. Its proofs require a counting argument to establish that $-1$ is a quadratic residue. (The theory can formalize the infinite descent argument that *if* $-1$ is a quadratic residue, *then* $m$ can be written as a sum of two squares.)

Comment: To clarify the above, Fermat’s two-square theorem is *equivalent* over $I\Delta_0$ to the statement $\bigl(\frac{-1}p\bigr)=1$ for prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$. This is not known to be provable even in $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$. See https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072(91)90096-5 and https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.200910009. The weakest extension of $I\Delta_0$ known to prove it is the theory $I\Delta_0+\mathrm{Count}_2(\Delta_0)$ with modulo-$2$ counting principles (actually, its subtheory $IE_1+\mathrm{Count_2}(\nabla_1)$ suffices), which actually proves the full quadratic reciprocity theorem.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, let me know if this is good now